# What was that in the box with Thomas?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-maze-runner

Re-watching **The Maze Runner**, I've noticed something at the very start of the movie...another figure is in the box with Thomas and it's never mentioned, the only mere mention is when Thomas reacted to seeing it.

At around 30 seconds, the scene shows a creature contained in the cage in the box. Is this a crank? Because the gladers never blinked an eye to it...

What is the story behind this??

Comment: Grievers are way too big for the box

Answer (score 1):

### No one actually knows.

This creature is unknown, and there is no information about it in the [Maze Runner Wiki](https://mazerunner.fandom.com/wiki/The_Box). I can just suppose it might be a guard who is watching after them.

For me, it looks like a simple (hungry) dog, relying on its sounds and size.

Answer (score -1):

They're sending up supplies along with Thomas. They've included a live pig as part of those supplies.

Comment: It wasn't a pig, look closely it has a face unlike a pig

Comment: @natural It looks like a dog.

Comment: But there was no mention as I said in the question

Comment: I think it looks like a pig.